# How to generate rsa-sha2-256 keys using ssh-keygen utility?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, rsa, ssh-keygen

I want to generate rsa-sha2-256 ssh key pair using ssh-keygen utility. Can you please share the command for the same?

For ssh-rsa, it's `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Comment: What have you tried? The default fingerprint_hash already is RSA-SHA2-256. Your question is extremely confusing

Comment: I tried with -t rsa, -t rsa-sha2-256 and -t rsa-sha2-512. In all cases, fingerprint_hash is sha256. I'm not able to make sense, how all are sha256?

Comment: Because what you are trying is not changing the default fingerprint hash. You would have to use `-E` to accomplish that, but you have indicated, you WANT to use a sha256 hash. The only two options are `md5` and `sha256`.  By default the key will be `rsa-sha2-512` which is more secure than `rsa-sha2-256`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the command:

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa-sha2-256 -b 2048
```

PS: Maybe you need to upgrade Openssh version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is one of information about options, https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/hp-virtual-servers?topic=hp-virtual-servers-generate_ssh&locale=en. Also, this work for me on windows 11 with openSSH for windows(9.4).

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it there is no such thing.

Specifically my understanding is that there is a distinction between key types and signature types. The "ssh-rsa" key type is used by the "ssh-rsa", "rsa-sha2-256" and "rsa-sha2-512" signature types.

The ssh-rsa signature type is being deprecated, because of security concerns surrounding sha1. However the ssh-rsa key type is still just fine, as long as the key length is sufficient.